# Exception Breakpoint fires when copying View Controller between projects

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode8

I've customized a tutorial and am trying to import it into my project.  After copying one View Controller Scene from Document Outline into my main project, it's throwing an exception without any description of the issue.  The View Controller is subclassed, so I've made sure to import the associated Swift file and set it in Document Attributes.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this one.

===EDIT===
I'm at a total loss here.  I created a new project and was able to import, build, and run the project.  The only difference between my main project and the new one is the VC is not the initial View Controller.
The tuturial was written in XCode 11 and Swift 4.  I haven't upgraded yet, but again I was able to import into a new project w/o issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Connections inspector** (the last option on the right sidebar) and make sure there are no connections with exclamation marks (**!**) after them.

If there are errors, check in the **Identity inspector** (the third option from the left on the right sidebar) if the class of the view controller is correct.

[image: Identity inspector with a class name]

If the connections are not needed anymore (you gave the outlet a new name etc.), remove them by clicking on the **X** next to them.

[image: Connections inspector]

Comment: I checked and they were connected (no exclamation point) .  I deleted and reconnected them just to make sure.  Unfortunately no luck.

Comment: Hey the4kman.  I've spent days on this.  Finally I just read... Turn off your exception breakpoint and it will probably work fine.  It did.  I'm not very good at debugging.